# Azure website node.js trigger deployment

Tags: node.js, git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a node.js project running on an azure website.
Usually I deploy changes with git (e.g. git push azure master).
Today I added a new branch 'newbranch' and committed some changes. Afterwards I pushed the changes to the azure website (git push azure dev).

Now I wanted to change the deployment from branch 'master'to branch 'newbranch'. Therefore, I went to the configure tab of my azure website and changed the field ‘branch to deploy’ to 'newbranch' and hit the save button.

But unlike to http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/ Section "Specifying the branch to use" azure does not start to deploy.

My current workaround is to change a file and do another push. Then the deployment process starts.

My question: Is there a better way to ‘manually’ trigger the deployment process?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it says at that URL is: "Azure should immediately begin updating based on changes to the new branch." It's confusing, but what it means is that next time you push to the newly configured branch, it will deploy from that branch. 
Website deployments are triggered by a webhook at the remote git repository. That means you need to make some change to the newly configured branch, which will in turn invoke the webhook against your website causing it to pull changes and deploy.

Making a push to your repo is the surest, easiest way to trigger the deployment.